# Kill xserver from command line (init 3/5 does not work)

Tags: linux, command-line, kill, init, x-server

I'm running Linux Mint 10, although I've had this same issue with other variants of Linux. I've been told/found while researching that if the X server hangs or otherwise errors, one can drop to a root prompt, usually at another tty, and execute `init 3` (to drop to single user mode) and then `init 5` to return to the default, graphical session.

Needless to say, I've tried this before in multiple configurations on multiple machines to no avail. The only feedback I receive form executing those two commands is a listing of VMWare services (from a kernel module) that are stopped and then restarted.

Note: If I run `startx` (either before or after `init 3`), then I am told that the xserver is still running and that I should remove `/tmp/.X0-lock`. Having tried that, it removes that error message, but claims that the xserver cannot be attached as another instance is running.

How do I kill the xserver completely? Can I `killall` some process name?

Comment: Just to call this out for emphasis, as @jsumners said, runlevel 3 is still multi-user.

Answer (score 4):

Linux Mint is based on Debian. In Debian, the single user run level is 1; 3 is still a multi-user run level and as such allows X to continue execution. So, you need to switch to run level 1, `init 1`, to stop all processes initiated by the default run level (2). Then you can re-init to the proper run level: `init 2`.

See [Debian run levels](http://www.debianadmin.com/debian-and-ubuntu-linux-run-levels.html) for more information.

Comment: +1 Good point, on Debian, runlevel 3 and runlevel 5 are the same thing.  See, e.g. `/etc/init/gdm.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to kill your X server is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

For example, on Ubuntu, the keyboard shortcut is called "DontZap", and can be re-enabled by following [these instructions](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/X/Config/DontZap).  It should be the same on Linux Mint.

---

It's best not to run `startx`.  It is independent from `init 3`/`init 5`, and will confuse things.

---

These days, `pkill` is preferred over `killall`.  It basically does the same thing, but it has a partner command `pgrep` you can use to see what it would kill before doing it.

So try `pgrep X` or `pgrep Xorg`, and then run `pkill X` or `pkill Xorg` if `pgrep` lists only programs you want to kill.

On my Ubuntu system, the most reliable command I can find is:

```
pgrep -f '^/usr/bin/X '
```

which means you can kill all X servers using

```
pkill -f '^/usr/bin/X '
```

(but I haven't tested it).

---

Finally, don't forget to have a look in `/var/log/X.0.log` and `~/.xsession-errors`.  Maybe you can figure out what is causing the X server hangs.

Comment: `Ctrl + Alt + Backspace` has been disabled for a reason, because there's a [Magic SysRq Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key), speak `Alt + Print + K` for it. Also, just for the record, Google is not considered helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When I update Xorg or video drivers:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Log in as a user
3. Type the following commands:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop #or slim gdm mdm etc...
   #do stuff
   sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start #or slim gdm mdm etc...
   ```

(Stopping the Display Manager also stops X.)