# Cannot kill Xorg process

Tags: linux, xorg, kill

On my Linux box, Xorg server got stuck and is consuming 100% CPU. It normally does not do that, but the machine has been suspended/resumed several times and the displays are not connected - I assume that might be what caused it.

The process does not react to kill -9 (as root). What can be the reason and how can I terminate/restart it?

Comment: [linux - Kill xserver from command line (init 3/5 does not work) - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/249257/kill-xserver-from-command-line-init-3-5-does-not-work)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, but that does not apply to me.